# Soring Data Reactive: Criteria API reactive

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm moving my repositories into `reactive` repositories.

I'm using webflux:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here my class:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QdCFCriteriaRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<QdCF> findByDataBaixaNull() {
        
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<QdCF> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(QdCF.class);

        Root<QdCF> qdcf = criteriaQuery.from(QdCF.class);
        Predicate dataBaixaPredicate = criteriaBuilder.isNull(qdcf.get("dataBaixa"));

        criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.where(dataBaixaPredicate);

        TypedQuery<QdCF> query = this.entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
    
}
```

I don't quite figure out how to move this criteria code to reactive criteria code.

I mean, How could I get a `Mono of List<QdCF>`?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA does not support the Spring WebFlux. If you like Hibernate/JPA APIs and stick on the WebFlux statck, try to use Hibernate Reactive instead.

Unfortunately Spring Data team have no plan to integrate Hibernate Reactive, see:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1178
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2503

Reading [my blog to integrate Hibernate Reactive with Spring yourself](https://itnext.io/integrating-hibernate-reactive-with-spring-5427440607fe), it is just a piece of cake if you are familiar with Spring.